# localhost:5672 call is not possible in Php RabbitMQ. How should I modify the rabbitmq.conf file?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

environment :
Rocky Linux release 9.2 (Blue Onyx)

Perhaps the APServer accessed via ssh cannot access the RabbitMQ server (localhost:5672=127.0.0.1:5672) on the same IP as the APServer..!

```
$this->connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
```

What settings should I touch??

Currently, you can edit the rabbitmq.conf file and connect as 'guest'.

```
loopback_users = none
```

The architecture is

[APServer(php) <-> RabbitMQ] <-> DBServer

For reference, APServer(php) <-> RabbitMQ has the same IP, only the port number is different.

What options should I give to call localhost:5672?
Could it be that rabbitmq.conf is not the cause?